# Incremental solver and unsatisfiable cores with quantified formulas

Tags: z3

I'm trying to perform a sequence of calls to z3 (using the python interface) on formulas of the form:

```
1. ForAll([x, y], F)
2. ForAll([x, y, z], F)
3. ForAll([x, z], F)
```

Essentially I need to add and remove quantifiers on demand. Since the formulas all share the same body, I'm interested in exploiting the advantages of an incremental solver.  Moreover, suppose that the call on the first formula of the example is satisfiable, while the call on the second is unsatisfiable. I would like the solver to return an unsatisfiable core containing the quantified variable z. I know that in z3 it is possible to use assumptions with constraints, but to the best of my knowledge this is not possible with quantifiers.
Is there a way to achieve all this with z3?